# wireless control with low delay/latency

Tags: ros

for a remote control application I am looking for a way to transfer data at 50 kbit per sec over a range of 10 meters with a concrete wall in between. The crucial requirement: Delay and jitter have to be less than 1 milli second.
is there any thing like a Arduino shield or ASIC which can do that?
BLE and WIFI have a longer delay, right?